# Recreating Form in PHP from ASP, Multiple results with dynamically generated drop downs?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I'm recreating a multi-Part form, but this question pertains specifically to a page where someone signing up can mark what (if any) commodities they may have or grow. You can see in my ASPX and ASPX.CS , how we have accomplished it thus far (mainly utilizing classes and some ajax/javascript). Now that we are recreating the system in PHP, I'm mulling over better (maybe simpler is a better word) ways to do this. Currently, the list of commodities is pulled from a SQL table, and a drop down is displayed next to each one (depending on it's unit of measurement - EX: Acre, Flock, Head, etc). After the joining member selects his crops, they are committed to a different table with his/her member ID and quantity of said commodity. See Below:

Question:
What, if there is one, is a better way to do this in PHP?

Thanks for your time =)

## commodities.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="commodities.aspx.cs" Inherits="Secure_commodities" MasterPageFile="~/secure/joinfb.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content> 

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" Runat="Server">
<style type="text/css"> 
        collapsePanel {

            background-color:white;
            overflow:hidden;

        }

        collapsePanelHeader{
            width:100%;
            height:30px; 
            border-color: Red;
            color:#FFF;
            font-weight:bold;
        } 
.panelImage{
vertical-align:baseline;

}
    </style>
     <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="tk1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
     <p class="formHeading"><b>Member Commodities</b></p>
      <p>
        <label>
            Do you include any of the following production practices in your operation?
        </label>
      </p>
      <table width="50%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
      <tr>
        <td>
             <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOCC" runat="server" Text="Organic Crop Certification" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkUSDA" runat="server" Text="USDA Conservation Program" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    <br/>
       <p class="formHeading">
       <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
       <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" CssClass="panelImage" /> <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat="server" Text="Dairy/Livestock/Poultry" Font-Size="Medium" /> <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" />
       </asp:Panel>


        <%--<asp:ImageButton ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/bg-menu-main.png" AlternateText="(Show Details...)"/> --%> 
        <%--<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">(Show Details...)</asp:Label></p>--%>  
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="collapsePanel" Height="0">
            <asp:datalist id="dtlList1" DataKeyField="CMDY_Code" Width="100%" RepeatColumns="3" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Bind_Unit_1"
                CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: auto" align="left" >
                                    <asp:CheckBox Runat="server" ID="chk1" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 45%" align="left">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle1" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Commodity") %>'  />
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 50%" align="left">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" Runat="server" CssClass="input" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dlQuantityChanged1" /> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:datalist>
        </asp:Panel>

        <ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender0" runat="Server"
        TargetControlID="Panel1"
        ExpandControlID="pnl1"
        CollapseControlID="pnl1"  
        Collapsed="True"      
        SuppressPostBack="false" 
        ImageControlID="img1" CollapsedImage="http://test.com/images/expand_blue.jpg" ExpandedImage="../images/collapse_blue.jpg" 
        TextLabelID="lbl1" CollapsedText="&nbsp;" ExpandedText="&nbsp;"        
         />

         <p class="formHeading">

         <asp:Panel ID="pnl2" runat="server">
       <asp:Image ID="img2" runat="server" CssClass="panelImage" /> <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk2" runat="server" Text="Field Crops" Font-Size="Medium" />  <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" />
       </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="collapsePanel" Height="0">
            <asp:datalist id="dtlList2" DataKeyField="CMDY_Code" Width="100%" RepeatColumns="3" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Bind_Unit_2"
                CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: auto" align="left" >
                                    <asp:CheckBox Runat="server" ID="chk1" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 45%" align="left">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle1" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Commodity") %>'  />
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 50%" align="left">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" Runat="server" CssClass="input" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dlQuantityChanged2" /> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:datalist>
        </asp:Panel>

        <ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender1" runat="Server"
        TargetControlID="Panel2"
        ExpandControlID="pnl2"
        CollapseControlID="pnl2"  
        Collapsed="True"      
        SuppressPostBack="false" 
        ImageControlID="img2" CollapsedImage="http://test.com/images/expand_blue.jpg" ExpandedImage="../images/collapse_blue.jpg" 
        TextLabelID="lbl2" CollapsedText="&nbsp;" ExpandedText="&nbsp;"  
         />


          <p class="formHeading">
          <asp:Panel ID="pnl3" runat="server">
       <asp:Image ID="img3" runat="server"  CssClass="panelImage"/> <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk3" runat="server" Text="Horticulture/Forestry" Font-Size="Medium" />  <asp:Label ID="lbl3" runat="server" />
       </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" CssClass="collapsePanel" Height="0">
            <asp:datalist id="dtlList3" DataKeyField="CMDY_Code" Width="100%" RepeatColumns="3" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Bind_Unit_3"
                CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: auto" align="left" >
                                    <asp:CheckBox Runat="server" ID="chk1" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 45%" align="left">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle1" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Commodity") %>'  />
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 50%" align="left">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" Runat="server" CssClass="input" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dlQuantityChanged3" /> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:datalist>
        </asp:Panel>

        <ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender2" runat="Server"

        TargetControlID="Panel3"
        ExpandControlID="pnl3"
        CollapseControlID="pnl3"  
        Collapsed="True"      
        SuppressPostBack="false" 
        ImageControlID="img3" CollapsedImage="http://test.com/images/expand_blue.jpg" ExpandedImage="../images/collapse_blue.jpg" 
        TextLabelID="lbl3" CollapsedText="&nbsp;" ExpandedText="&nbsp;" 
         />

          <p class="formHeading">
          <asp:Panel ID="pnl4" runat="server">
       <asp:Image ID="img4" runat="server"  CssClass="panelImage"/> <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk4" runat="server" Text="Trees/Vines" Font-Size="Medium" />  <asp:Label ID="lbl4" runat="server" />
       </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" CssClass="collapsePanel" Height="0">
            <asp:datalist id="dtlList4" DataKeyField="CMDY_Code" Width="100%" RepeatColumns="3" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Bind_Unit_4"
                CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: auto" align="left" >
                                    <asp:CheckBox Runat="server" ID="chk1" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 45%" align="left">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle1" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Commodity") %>'  />
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 50%" align="left">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" Runat="server" CssClass="input" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dlQuantityChanged4" /> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:datalist>
        </asp:Panel>

        <ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender3" runat="Server"
        TargetControlID="Panel4"
        ExpandControlID="pnl4"
        CollapseControlID="pnl4"  
        Collapsed="True"      
        SuppressPostBack="false" 
        ImageControlID="img4" CollapsedImage="http://test.com/images/expand_blue.jpg" ExpandedImage="../images/collapse_blue.jpg" 
        TextLabelID="lbl4" CollapsedText="&nbsp;" ExpandedText="&nbsp;"  
         />

          <p class="formHeading">
          <asp:Panel ID="pnl5" runat="server">
       <asp:Image ID="img5" runat="server"  CssClass="panelImage"/> <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk5" runat="server" Text="Vegetables" Font-Size="Medium" />  <asp:Label ID="lbl5" runat="server" />
       </asp:Panel>


        <asp:Panel ID="Panel5" runat="server" CssClass="collapsePanel" Height="0">
            <asp:datalist id="dtlList5" DataKeyField="CMDY_Code" Width="100%" RepeatColumns="3" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Bind_Unit_5"
                CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: auto" align="left" >
                                    <asp:CheckBox Runat="server" ID="chk1" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 45%" align="left">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle1" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Commodity") %>'  />
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 50%" align="left">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" Runat="server" CssClass="input" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dlQuantityChanged5" /> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:datalist>
        </asp:Panel>

        <ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender4" runat="Server"
        TargetControlID="Panel5"
        ExpandControlID="pnl5"
        CollapseControlID="pnl5"  
        Collapsed="True"      
        SuppressPostBack="false" 
        ImageControlID="img5" CollapsedImage="http://test.com/images/expand_blue.jpg" ExpandedImage="../images/collapse_blue.jpg" 
        TextLabelID="lbl5" CollapsedText="&nbsp;" ExpandedText="&nbsp;"
         />
         <p>
            <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="btnNext_OnClick" />
         </p>

     </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Content>
```

## commodities.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using TESTReg;

public partial class Secure_commodities : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Load_DList();

            if (Request.QueryString["Mode"] == "Edit")
            {
                // populate each CMDY
                Membership Member = new Membership();
                Member = (Membership)Session.Contents["Membership"];

                Load_CMDY(dtlList1, Member, CollapsiblePanelExtender0);
                Load_CMDY(dtlList2, Member, CollapsiblePanelExtender1);
                Load_CMDY(dtlList3, Member, CollapsiblePanelExtender2);
                Load_CMDY(dtlList4, Member, CollapsiblePanelExtender3);
                Load_CMDY(dtlList5, Member, CollapsiblePanelExtender4);

                //List<Commodity> list = new List<Commodity>();

                //for (int i = 0; i < Member.Commodities.Count; i++)
                //{
                //    list.Add(Member.Commodities[i]);
                //}

                //dlChildren.DataSource = list;
                ////dlChildren.DataBind();

                //foreach (DataListItem li in dlChildren.Items)
                //{
                //    TextBox tFname = (TextBox)(li.FindControl("txtChildFName"));
                //    TextBox tLname = (TextBox)(li.FindControl("txtChildLName"));
                //    TextBox tDOB = (TextBox)(li.FindControl("txtChildDOB"));

                //    tFname.Text = Member.Dependent[li.ItemIndex].FirstName;
                //    tLname.Text = Member.Dependent[li.ItemIndex].LastName;
                //    tDOB.Text = Member.Dependent[li.ItemIndex].DOB;
                //}

                //ddlNumChild.ClearSelection();
                //ddlNumChild.Items.FindByValue(Member.Dependent.Count.ToString()).Selected = true;

            }
        }
    }

    private void Load_CMDY(DataList dl, Membership Member, AjaxControlToolkit.CollapsiblePanelExtender cp)
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < Member.Commodities.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (DataListItem li in dl.Items)
            {
                CheckBox _chk = (CheckBox)(li.FindControl("chk1"));
                DropDownList _ddl = (DropDownList)(li.FindControl("ddl1"));

                if (Member.Commodities[i].Cmdy_Code == dl.DataKeys[li.ItemIndex].ToString())
                {
                    _chk.Checked = Member.Commodities[i].SelectedItem;
                    _ddl.ClearSelection();
                    _ddl.Items.FindByValue(Member.Commodities[i].Unit_Value).Selected = true;
                    cp.Collapsed = false;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

    }

    private void Load_DList()
    {
        string sSQL;

        sSQL = "SELECT CMDY_CODE, Commodity, Category FROM _WJ_TBL_Commodity WHERE Category='Dairy/Livestock/Poultry' ORDER BY Commodity";
        System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        ds = Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JoinFB_Conn"].ConnectionString,
             System.Data.CommandType.Text, sSQL);
        dtlList1.DataSource = ds;
        dtlList1.DataBind();

        sSQL = "SELECT CMDY_CODE, Commodity, Category FROM _WJ_TBL_Commodity WHERE Category='Field Crops' ORDER BY Commodity";
        ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        ds = Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JoinFB_Conn"].ConnectionString,
         System.Data.CommandType.Text, sSQL);
        dtlList2.DataSource = ds;
        dtlList2.DataBind();

        sSQL = "SELECT CMDY_CODE, Commodity, Category FROM _WJ_TBL_Commodity WHERE Category='Horticulture/Forestry' ORDER BY Commodity";
        ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        ds = Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JoinFB_Conn"].ConnectionString,
         System.Data.CommandType.Text, sSQL);
        dtlList3.DataSource = ds;
        dtlList3.DataBind();

        sSQL = "SELECT CMDY_CODE, Commodity, Category FROM _WJ_TBL_Commodity WHERE Category='Trees/Vines' ORDER BY Commodity";
        ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        ds = Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JoinFB_Conn"].ConnectionString,
         System.Data.CommandType.Text, sSQL);
        dtlList4.DataSource = ds;
        dtlList4.DataBind();

        sSQL = "SELECT CMDY_CODE, Commodity, Category FROM _WJ_TBL_Commodity WHERE Category='Vegetables' ORDER BY Commodity";
        ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        ds = Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JoinFB_Conn"].ConnectionString,
         System.Data.CommandType.Text, sSQL);
        dtlList5.DataSource = ds;
        dtlList5.DataBind();
    }

    protected void dlQuantityChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList _dl = (DropDownList)sender;

        DataListItem _dlItem = (DataListItem)_dl.NamingContainer;

        // get id of row
        CheckBox _chk = (CheckBox)_dlItem.FindControl("chk1");

        CheckCMDY(_chk, _dl);
    }

    protected void dlQuantityChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList _dl = (DropDownList)sender;

        DataListItem _dlItem = (DataListItem)_dl.NamingContainer;

        // get id of row
        CheckBox _chk = (CheckBox)_dlItem.FindControl("chk1");

        CheckCMDY(_chk, _dl);
    }

    protected void dlQuantityChanged3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList _dl = (DropDownList)sender;

        DataListItem _dlItem = (DataListItem)_dl.NamingContainer;

        // get id of row
        CheckBox _chk = (CheckBox)_dlItem.FindControl("chk1");

        CheckCMDY(_chk, _dl);
    }

    protected void dlQuantityChanged4(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList _dl = (DropDownList)sender;

        DataListItem _dlItem = (DataListItem)_dl.NamingContainer;

        // get id of row
        CheckBox _chk = (CheckBox)_dlItem.FindControl("chk1");

        CheckCMDY(_chk, _dl);
    }

    protected void dlQuantityChanged5(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList _dl = (DropDownList)sender;

        DataListItem _dlItem = (DataListItem)_dl.NamingContainer;

        // get id of row
        CheckBox _chk = (CheckBox)_dlItem.FindControl("chk1");

        CheckCMDY(_chk, _dl);
    }

    private void CheckCMDY(CheckBox chk, DropDownList dl)
    {
        if (dl.SelectedIndex > 0)
            chk.Checked = true;
    }

    protected void Bind_Unit_1(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    { 
        Bind_DDL_Unit(e, dtlList1, "ddl1");
    }

    protected void Bind_Unit_2(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    { 
        Bind_DDL_Unit(e, dtlList2, "ddl1");
    }

    protected void Bind_Unit_3(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Bind_DDL_Unit(e, dtlList3, "ddl1");
    }

    protected void Bind_Unit_4(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Bind_DDL_Unit(e, dtlList4, "ddl1");
    }

    protected void Bind_Unit_5(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Bind_DDL_Unit(e, dtlList5, "ddl1");
    }

    protected void Bind_DDL_Unit(DataListItemEventArgs e, DataList dtlList, string cmdy_ddl)
    {
        string sSQL;
        DropDownList ddl;
        int x;

        sSQL = "select DISTINCT m.Unit_CODE FROM _WJ_TBL_Unit m, _WJ_TBL_Commodity s WHERE s.CMDY_CODE=@CMDY_CODE and m.unit_Code=s.unit_Code";
        // Retrieve Unit Code first
        x = Convert.ToInt32(Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JoinFB_Conn"].ConnectionString,
            System.Data.CommandType.Text, sSQL, new SqlParameter("@CMDY_CODE", dtlList.DataKeys[dtlList.Items.Count])));

        if (x > 0)
        {
            sSQL = "SELECT Unit, Unit_Value FROM _WJ_TBL_Unit WHERE Unit_Code=@Unit_Code";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JoinFB_Conn"].ConnectionString,
            System.Data.CommandType.Text, sSQL, new SqlParameter("@Unit_Code", x));

            ddl = (DropDownList)(e.Item.FindControl(cmdy_ddl));
            ddl.DataSource = ds;
            ddl.DataTextField = "Unit";
            ddl.DataValueField = "Unit_Value";
            ddl.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void btnNext_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TESTReg.Membership MemberInfo = new TESTReg.Membership(); 
        MemberInfo = (TESTReg.Membership)Session.Contents["Membership"];

        //MemberInfo.CMDY.Clear();
        //MemberInfo.Produce.Clear();
        MemberInfo.Commodities.Clear();

        // Process Datalist
        ProcessCMDY(dtlList1, MemberInfo, "ddl1", "chk1", "lblTitle1");
        ProcessCMDY(dtlList2, MemberInfo, "ddl1", "chk1", "lblTitle1");
        ProcessCMDY(dtlList3, MemberInfo, "ddl1", "chk1", "lblTitle1");
        ProcessCMDY(dtlList4, MemberInfo, "ddl1", "chk1", "lblTitle1");
        ProcessCMDY(dtlList5, MemberInfo, "ddl1", "chk1", "lblTitle1");

        if (chkOCC.Checked)
            MemberInfo.Organic_Crop_Cert = true;
        else
            MemberInfo.Organic_Crop_Cert = false;

        if (chkUSDA.Checked)
            MemberInfo.USDA_Cons_Prog = true;
        else
            MemberInfo.USDA_Cons_Prog = false;

        Session.Contents["Membership"] = MemberInfo;

        if (Request.QueryString["Mode"] == "Edit")
            Response.Redirect("confirmation.aspx");
        else
            Response.Redirect("Payment.aspx");
    }

    private void ProcessCMDY(DataList dl, TESTReg.Membership MemberInfo, string ddlist, string chkbox, string lbel)
    {

        // Saves commodity checked
        foreach (DataListItem di in dl.Items)
        {
            DropDownList ddl;
            CheckBox chk;
            Label lbl;


            ddl = (DropDownList)(di.FindControl(ddlist));
            chk = (CheckBox)(di.FindControl(chkbox));
            lbl = (Label)(di.FindControl(lbel));

            if (chk.Checked)
            {

                TESTReg.Commodity Commodities = new TESTReg.Commodity();

                //MemberInfo.CMDY.Add(dl.DataKeys[di.ItemIndex]);
                //MemberInfo.Produce.Add(ddl.SelectedItem.Value); 
                Commodities.Cmdy_Code = dl.DataKeys[di.ItemIndex].ToString();
                Commodities.Unit_Value = Convert.ToString(ddl.SelectedItem.Value);
                Commodities.Unit_Amt = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
                Commodities.Cmdy = lbl.Text;
                Commodities.SelectedItem = chk.Checked;

                MemberInfo.Commodities.Add(Commodities);
            }

        }


        //string t1;
        //string t2;
        //for (int i = 0; i < MemberInfo.Commodities.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    t1 = MemberInfo.Commodities[i].Cmdy;
        //    t2 = MemberInfo.Commodities[i].Unit_Amt;
        //}
        //return MemberInfo;
    }




}
```

Comment: I have created many dynamic drop down list using PHP, jQuery, and various data stores, from xml to json. The logic should be the same, when the user changes a dropdown, you make an ajax call to an endpoint with the selected item -> use that info in your query -> return the correct info to the ajax call -> use jQuery to update the page.

Comment: I have not recreated this page in PHP yet. As it stands, I've recreated up to this step - but felt I should inquire with the community before I try to translate a page vs rebuild it from the ground up. I would rather spend my time doing it the "best way" rather than it just "working".

Comment: @JaredAquaReece I don't think there is a best way, but having done this a few times -> i think an ajax call to a php page that handles the query works nicely since you don't have to refresh the page or redirect the user. You can also use this to add some security into the app, and your php code can live on a different server and you can enable CORS - more security. In fact you can return JSON and if you wanna go bananas just make a light weight API ahha. Maybe that is a bit extreme.

Comment: That answered my question exactly then @Radmation. Thank you!